# Check if list has object by 2 properties

Tags: c#, list

I would like to check if there is any cell in my list of cells that has a specific column and also a specific row, and if there is, delete that cell. If there is not, add a cell with that row and column. My attempt, but unable to check row as not sure how to check 2 properties:

```
int index = cells.FindIndex(item => item.myColumn == col);
if (index >= 0)
{
    // element exists, do what you need
    if (cell.myColumn == col && cell.myRow == row)
    {
        cells.Remove(cell);
    }
}
else
{
    Bitmap image = myMapController.myMap.cellBgImage;
    cells.Add(new Cell(col, row, new CellSide(0, false), new CellSide(0, false), myMapController.myMap, image));
}
```

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from doing `item => item.myColumn == col && item.myRow == row` on the first line?

Comment: No. That works, no errors. Thanks. Just new to this.